# Laravel 5.1 issue implementing global scope

Tags: php, laravel, scope

So I am trying to create a global scope in laravel 5.1 but just keep on getting the following error `Trait 'Eloquent\Scopes\DependentTypeTrait' not found`.

Here is my code:

App\Models\Eloquent\Scopes\DependentTypeTrait.php:

```
<?php namespace App\Models\Eloquent\Scopes;

trait DependentTypeTrait {

    /**
     * Boot the Active Events trait for a model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public static function bootDependentTypeTrait()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new DependentTypeScope);
    }

}
```

App\Models\Eloquent\Scopes\DependentTypeScope.php:

```
<?php namespace App\Models\Eloquent\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ScopeInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class DependentTypeScope implements ScopeInterface
{

    public function apply(Builder $builder)
    {
        $builder->where('vip_type_id', 2);
    }

    public function remove(Builder $builder)
    {

        $query = $builder->getQuery();

        // here you remove the where close to allow developer load
        // without your global scope condition

        foreach ((array) $query->wheres as $key => $where) {

            if ($where['column'] == 'vip_type_id') {

                unset($query->wheres[$key]);

                $query->wheres = array_values($query->wheres);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

App\Models\Dependent.php:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Eloquent\Scopes\DependentTypeTrait;

class Dependent extends Model
{

    use DependentTypeTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = '<my table name>';

    /**
     * The actual primary key for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = '<my primary key>';

}
```

I feel like I have the namespacing correct but its still saying it can't find the attribute....any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the use namespace wrong when trying to import your `DependentTypeTrait`:

```
<?php namespace App\Models\Eloquent\Scopes;

trait DependentTypeTrait { //...
```

And then you use it in `App\Models\Dependent`:

```
use Eloquent\Scopes\DependentTypeTrait;
```

Those namespaces don't match. Try this instead:

```
use App\Models\Eloquent\Scopes\DependentTypeTrait;
```

Or you can modify your `composer.json` to change how the `Eloquent` namespace is autoloaded:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Eloquent\\": "app/Models/Eloquent"
    }
},
```

And don't forget to dump your autoloader:  `$ composer dump-autoload`

Though specifically because you're using the name `Eloquent` which is ubiquitous in Laravel, I wouldn't go this route myself even if you would save yourself some typing. Laravel itself uses the namespace `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent` so you're probably safe from conflicts for now, but the possibility exists if Taylor changes things around or you use a third party library that stomps on it.

Comment: You are correct! I was assuming that since the namespace on the model was App\Namespace that I didn't have to add this in on the use....